# Worklight Adapter authentication required

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8, worklight-adapters

I'm using Worklight 6.0.0.1 which deployed on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.0 and I have my Application which using 2 HTTP adapters.

In the first adapter I putted my Login and logout functions (based form authentication).
In the second adapter I putted some others procedures.

So my problem is as bellow :

When I deployed Worklight (.war) on WebSphere and my other WAR file which containing the Webservices on an other server (Tomcat), Things is going good.

But when I deployed the WAR of worklight and the one containing my Webservices on the same server (WebSphere Liberty), things going wrong with the second adapter (the one that doesn't contain the login function). In each invocation procedure in the second Adapter, I get "**authentication required**" as response.

But when I invoke a procedure in the first adapter, it returns me the right response.

any idea ? I couldn't figure out the problem

I add that I'm calling the same web services in the two adapter.

This is the log I get :

```
{"status":200,"invocationContext":null,"invocationResult":{"responseID":"64","statusCode":200,"result":{},"errors":["authentication required"],"isSuccessful":true,"statusReason":"OK","responseHeaders":{"Content-Language":"en-US","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Date":"Thu, 05 Dec 2013 06:13:15 GMT","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0"},"success":0,"totalTime":280,"responseTime":271}}
```

Comment: Is there a fuller error log available? If so, please edit the question with it.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a procedure in your first adapter, does it call the web service?
If not, I'm assuming that only the second adapter is trying to access the web service.

Considering that, I'm guessing your Tomcat server is not securing the web service. Which means that you can access your web service without any authentication.

WAS or Liberty on the other hand could have application security enabled. Which means that if you try to access your web service deployed on WAS or Liberty, you will be prompted for authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your response, But I'm calling the same web service in the first adapter

Answer (score 0):

As it works with WAS and Tomcat, the issue seems occurring only under Liberty Profile. In this case only the Worklight trace and the Liberty Profile security trace can allow to understand the possible cause of the issue.